# Heroku app always calls local host from the frontend

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern

I am reading the host using window.location.hostname.But upon deploying the app in heroku it always calls the localhost.How to fix this?

I tried with 'http://app.herokuapp.com/api' and '/api/data' which doesnt work.

```
fetch(host+"/data")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(users => dispatch(loaddataSuccess(data)))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: why not write the real URL in the `host` variable? Instead of deriving it from the browser?

Comment: I did so..even then it behaves the same

Comment: There's not enough detail in here to answer your question. Can you add how you handle the request on your back-end? Also include the logs of the error in your response